# Slider shows pagination for 2 slides when there is only one

Tags: jquery, html, css

At the bottom of the following page, under the heading "Some Clients"
http://andrewmarc.co.uk/
the slider paginates for 2 slides when there is infract only only slide being showed (on a desktop viewport size)

Even when the images on the slider are shown at 100px wide, the slider still maintains the orignal width and paginates for 2 slides

Is there a way in which this can be solved

Comment: it shows 4 slide....please justify your question little more

Comment: on any viewport above 960px the slider paginates for 2 slides

Comment: I'm above 960px and I can see pagination for 4 slides.